# Оптимизация запросов к БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть два таких запроса:

```
$db->Query("
    SELECT DISTINCT(v.id), v.name
    FROM `vendor` v
    WHERE v.id IN(
    SELECT t.vendor_id FROM `tovar` t WHERE t.cat_id=$cid
    )
");

$db->Query("
    SELECT DISTINCT(tf.id_filter), f.name
    FROM `tovar_has_filter` tf
    LEFT JOIN `filter` f ON f.id=tf.id_filter
    WHERE tf.id_tovar IN(
    SELECT t.id FROM `tovar` t WHERE t.cat_id=$cid
    )
");
```

$cid - текущая категория.
Можно ли их объединить?

Точнее, есть 4 таблицы: tovar, vendor, filter, tovar_has_filter

связь между ними такая:

```
tovar.id_vendor=vendor.id
tovar_has_filter.id_tovar=tovar.id
filter.id=tovar_has_filter.id_filter
```

В таблице tovar имеется > 12000 записей. Запрос на выходе должен иметь все вендоры и фильтры товаров выбранной категории. Например, если в категории 20 товаров, то к каждому товару прикреплены вендоры и каждый товар имеет несколько фильтров. Например, если это материнская плата, то у нее вендор Inter и несколько фильтров такие как: chipset, поддерживаемая память, сокет, поддерживаемые процы.

На выходе должны быть название вендоров и название всех фильтров текущей категории. Это нужно для сортировки. Вот на сайте, то что я сделал двумя запросами: [пример](http://www.servershop.pro/index.php?mod=category&cid=78)
Запрос обрабатывается более 3 (3.66) секунд. Как можно оптимизировать запросы?

Comment: А что значит объединить? Сущности возвращаются разные. В разные столбцы объединить или просто в одном столбце сразу и фильтры и вендоры?

Comment: Задача бессмысленна, оптимизацией тут бы и не пахло

Comment: @AlexWindHope и почему же задача бессмысленна? Задачи не ми с вами ставим, а заказчик.

Comment: Бессмыслена  задача потому, что за ней нет никакого PROFIT'a.

Тупая трата времени разработчика и денег заказчика, ИМХО

Comment: @AlexWindHope Вы конкретно про эту задачу или про сам сайт?

Comment: Конкретно про эту задачу разумеется

Comment: Если честно, не понимаю связь между профит и этой задачей. Я вас не понимаю :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без вложенных запросов будет быстрее:

1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.vendor_id, v.name
FROM `tovar` t
LEFT JOIN `vendor` v ON t.vendor_id = v.id
WHERE t.cat_id = $cid
```

2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT tf.id_filter, f.name
FROM `tovar` t
LEFT JOIN `tovar_has_filter` tf ON t.id = tf.id_tovar
LEFT JOIN `filter` f ON tf.id_filter = f.id
WHERE t.cat_id = $cid
```

Если все же надо "объединить" запросы, то между ними ставим UNION ALL и добавляем статический доп столбец чтоб отделить мух от котлет.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `v`, t.vendor_id, v.name
FROM `tovar` t
LEFT JOIN `vendor` v ON t.vendor_id = v.id
WHERE t.cat_id = $cid
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT `f`, tf.id_filter, f.name
FROM `tovar` t
LEFT JOIN `tovar_has_filter` tf ON t.id = tf.id_tovar
LEFT JOIN `filter` f ON tf.id_filter = f.id
WHERE t.cat_id = $cid
```

если я правильно понял задачу...

Comment: Неправильно все это.
Если есть в категории 3 товара материнок Асус1, Асус2 и Интел и к ним привязаны вендоры Асус к первым двум и Интел к Интелуовской мат-ке, и если фильтры к Асус1 = ф1,ф2,ф3 и к Асус2=ф2,ф3 и к Интел = ф5,ф1,ф3

то результатом должны быть 

Вендоры: Асус, Интел

Фильтры: ф1,ф2,ф3,ф5


Можно без объеденений, двумя запросами, но запросы выполняются 3-4 сек...главное с этим справиться. Спасибо


Ваши запросы выводят только одну запись.